# Physics2D.OverlapCircle only "false"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My problem is that I'm doing a Mario Bros style game in Unity and I need to know when the character is on the ground with a boolean and only returns false.

```
//Variables movimento
public float velocidadX = 0.1f;
public float movimentoX;
public float inputX;

//Vaiables salto
public float fuerzaSalto = 340f;
public Transform pie;
public float radioPie;
public LayerMask suelo;
public bool enSuelo;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate () {

    //Movimento

    float inputX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"); //Almacena el movimento en el eje X "A o D | <- o ->".

    if (inputX > 0)
    {
        movimentoX = transform.position.x + (inputX * velocidadX);
        transform.position = new Vector3(movimentoX, transform.position.y, 0);
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
    }

    if (inputX < 0)
    {
        movimentoX = transform.position.x + (inputX * velocidadX);
        transform.position = new Vector3(movimentoX, transform.position.y, 0);
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
    }

    //Salto

    enSuelo = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(pie.position, radioPie, suelo);
    Debug.Log(enSuelo);
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce (new Vector2(0,fuerzaSalto));
    }

}
```

[image: Image showing console results]

Comment: Well, to me it doesn't look like your player is even touching the ground. Also, what's wrong with doing a Raycast straight down from Marios feet?

Comment: A couple of problems preventing me from helping. 1) What is the variable name of your Mario character in this code? 2) What is the radius and what's the radius of the Mario's collider? 3) Do the ground tiles have a collider? 4) What is your layer mask? 5) What layers are the ground blocks?